# passing array of int to constructor by reference

Tags: c++, avr

I'm working on program for AVR using c++

To use less memory I want to pass pointer to predefined array of int thru constructor to class member, to access array using OOP

I can't define this array in constructor, because it's a lib class and this array and its size will be changed in other programs using this lib class

Code:

```
class A
{
    private:
        const unsigned char arr[];
        unsigned char arrSize;
    public:
        A(const unsigned char arr[],unsigned char arrSize)
        {
            this->arr = arr;
            this->arrSize=arrSize;
        }
};
```

Got next error on compilation:

> incompatible types in assignment of 'unsigned char*' to 'unsigned char [0]

I understand that i did somthing wrong, but i can't realize what exactly wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: So should a `A` just point to the array or does it need to own the array?

Comment: just point to array

Comment: const can only be initialized using initializer list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments you say you just need a pointer to the array.  To do that you just need a pointer in your class.  It should look  something like

```
class A
{
    private:
        const unsigned char* arr; // just use a pointer here
        unsigned char arrSize;
    public:
        A(const unsigned char arr[],unsigned char arrSize) : arr(arr), arrSize(arrSize) {}
        //                    ^^^^^ this decays to a const unsigned char*
};
```

I will caution you that this design can be problematic.  If the class object outlives the array it points to and you use the pointer then you have undefined behavior as you no longer know what is in that space anymore.

Comment: so, i'll can use `this->arr[0]`,`this->arr[1]` or similar code in class, or not? even if i use not `uint` but `struct` or any other? it's not related to my task but just to understand things, thanks)

Comment: @E.Monogarov Yes you can use `this->arr[0]` or just `arr[0]` inside the class.

Comment: it might not be broblematic as this array presents alive for all program running time

Answer (score -1):

You cannot assign to a `const`, not even in the constructor. Instead you need to initialize the const at the beginning of the constructor with the ':' syntax:

`A(const unsigned char Arr[],unsigned char arrSize) : arr{Arr}`

Comment: I don't think this will compile. You need to specify the size, at compile time, of the `arr` member. Are you doing that?